# PHP strpos() finds just single characters, not a whole string

Tags: php, strpos

I have a strange problem...

I would like to search in a logfile.

```
$lines = file($file);

$sampleName = "T3173sGas";

foreach ($lines as &$line) {

if (strpos($line, $sampleName) !== false) {
echo "yes";
  }
}
```

This code is not working, `$sampleName` is to `100%` in the log file. The search works just for single characters; for example `"T"` or `"3"` but not for `"T3"`.

Do you have an idea why it's not working? Is the encoding of the logfile wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It is possible that the encoding of the logfile is UTF-16, in which case `strpos` would not work for multiple characters but would still work for singles. Try [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you can only find single characters I would assume that your logfile is in some multi-byte character set like UTF-16. As you already assume similar, next step for you is to consult the documentation / specification of the logfile you're trying to operate with regarding the character encoding.

You then can use character-encoding specific string functions, the package is called http://php.net/mbstring.

```
$encoding = ... ; // encoding of logfile

if (mb_strpos($line, $sampleName, 0, $encoding) !== false) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I wrote: "$encoding = "UTF-16"; and then "if (mb_strpos($line, $sampleName, 0, $encoding) !== false) {...}" but without success :(

Comment: You skipped the most important part: to find out about the concrete encoding first. Encoding does not work well with guessing, it only works well with knowing. If you have problems to find out, provide a sample from the logfile, both plain-text as well as a hexdump. Also specify the system this logfile is part of.

Comment: Oh my goodness - that's hard stuff... I tried several things... a small software tells me, the encoding is "windows-1252"... but it doesn't work. When I use mb_detect_encoding($fileContent, "utf-8, windows-1251, windows-1252, iso-8859-1, ascii") it chooses iso-8859-1. But "iso-8859-1" doesn't work too. I'm lost :) Do you have any other idea? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well encoding is two folded. Now after you've checked the encoding of the logfile, check as well the encoding of your PHP file. ;) The string you enter in your PHP code *must* share the same encoding otherwise strpos won't do it.

Comment: ah, okay, now I understand - when the logfile is Windows-1252 and I would like to compare it with $sampleName, $sampleName has to be Windows-1252 too using mb_strpos? I will try it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: okay, stupid question... when I write in my code: $sampleName = "T3163GSa"; => which encoding is this string? I would like to use iconv() to convert the sampleName from XY to windows-1252...

Comment: The string is in the encoding of the PHP file you write that string in unless you use special escape sequences which would allow you to specify binary string values independent to the encoding of the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, it searches for the entire string

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.php';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$sampleName = "T3173sGas";
if(strlen(strstr($file,$sampleName))>0)
{
echo "yes"; 
}
?>
```